# What is the Golden Bee spawn rate?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

Has anyone confirmed the spawn rate for golden bees? I found several threads at various forums, but they all boil down to "just buy one".

I **know** I can buy them, and did in my file. However, my 6 year old son wants to catch one. He just caught his first shiny Pokemon, so he knows what patience means. I'd just like to be able to give him a number if possible.

---

**Regarding duplicate status:**

I don't believe this is a duplicate at all. I asked a specific question not covered by either the question *or* answer in the linked one. "It appears randomly" is **not** a spawn rate, and I thought that was clear from my original question.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I saw exactly one Golden Bee in my playthrough and I have encountered quite a lot of bees. They're findable, but rare.

Comment: Yea, I figured they were pretty rare. I haven't seen a wild one yet, with two sages left. My kid likes numbers, so I'm trying to give him a "target".

Comment: Not sure how this is a duplicate. The other question is about places or methods to more easily find a golden bee, while this question is about the chances of finding one as opposed to finding a regular bee. It's like the difference between `how do I win the lottery?` and `what are the chaces to win a lottery?`.

Comment: @Nolonar An incomplete answer is not a reason to ask a duplicate question.  The answer in my question just needs to be updated.  We don't need two golden bee questions.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot From the duplicate dialog: "If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to *explain how it is different* or ask a new question." From all my time on SE networks, this has been the normal way of doing it, which I did.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName I was one of the close voters (voted before I saw your 'Regarding duplicate status' explanation). I have since voted to reopen after seeing that. If this does not get reopened after a day or two, you could appeal that this question be reopened or ask for a discussion about the closing of this question at [meta].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Prima Guide, the spawn rate of a Golden Bee is 1/50.